# WicketTester with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, wicket, open-session-in-view, wicket-tester

I'm currently figuring out how to make my Wicket Application testable.

Basically, it is a Wicket / Hibernate / Apache Derby setup. Hibernate is used as a filter (as seen on: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView / see HibernateSessionRequestFilter) and has a hibernate.cfg.xml file as configuration.

What I want to do is be able to use WicketTester with a custom database that I can rebuild from scratch each testrun. Ideally, a test would contain the connection parameters for Hibernate

Basically, my question is on how to dynamically or at startup-time switch my database?

And more abstract: what is a good approach for this kind of testing?

Comment: I found this link, it helped my a bit: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365222/Unit-Testing-Hibernate-With-HSQLDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Unit Testing Hibernate with HSQLDB](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365222/Unit-Testing-Hibernate-With-HSQLDB).

Answer (score 1):

See [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) also. I used it in a lot tests - very helpful. 
Example:
    when(someDao.findByOwner(isA(Owner.class))).thenReturn(your-result);